# page unload event is firing up too many times

Tags: asp.net

I Have ten text boxes in my aspx page. Unload event in jscript to know if the user is exiting without saving the changes. But the problem is when ever we are editing any text box and going to the next textbox to edit, the page unload event is firing up. So literally, if i want to edit 10 textboxes, the event is firing up 10 times. Please suggest me

Comment: and what do you want to do?

Comment: I dont want the event to be fired when ever the text changes, but only when user try to navigate away from the page without saving the edited ones

Comment: Have you perhaps set a Text_Changed or Text_Focus event or similar to your textboxes?

Comment: Yes, I have a text changed event for the text boxes. But i need that text changed event to do some calculations.

Comment: Due to that text changed event, pageunload is firing up. I want to prevent it. I want unload event to be fired only when user changes data and tries to exit.

Comment: <div>
    <asp:Button ID = "btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" />
    <asp:TextBox ID = "TextBox" AutoPostBack =  "true" runat =  "server" OnTextChanged = "Changed" />
    <asp:TextBox ID = "TextBox1" AutoPostBack =  "false" runat = "server" OnTextChanged = "Changed1" />
    <asp:TextBox ID = "TextBox2" runat = "server" OnTextChanged = "Change2" />
    </div>

Comment: <script type ="text/javascript" >
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
    
  }

</script>

Comment: This is the code. But due to autopost back enabled for the 1st text bos, this pop is raising right after entering the text in the textbox.